# How to filter XHR requests without extension in Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: regex, google-chrome-devtools

I have used regex before but I'm no specialist. I've tried using stuff like `/[^\.]+\b` but I get too many results. I'm making request to another port on localhost (dev env) and since I'm using Angular 2 I'm fetching .js and .html files over XHR as well as normal REST calls.

I wan't to filter to only see REST XHR calls (ones without .js or .html extension). What would be the regex expression for this? As I've said, I've tried using `/[^\.]+\b` but it doesn't filter the ones ending with ".js".

requests which I want to avoid:

- http://localhost:9011/dist/services/ng2-file-upload2/ng2-file-upload.js
- http://localhost:9011/dist/services/form.js

requests which I do NOT want to avoid:

- http://localhost:9011/user/account/type
- http://localhost:8000/station/get

Comment: Google Chorme provides default filter only for XHRs, you can see it under Network tab Filter Tool Menu `XHR` [Visit](http://www.screencast.com/t/tqKRlHRihn)

Comment: Could you share a sample XHR call you need to match?

Comment: I have updated my question with examples

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can filter by MIME Type in the filter panel, among others:

[image: Filtering]

In your case, you could filter out CSS and HTML files with:

```
-mime-type:text/css -mime-type:text/html
```

I tried to come up with a regex, but it doesn't seem to work in DevTools. It does work in JavaScript though:

```
^.*\.(?!(css|html)$).*$
```

- Allow 0 or more of any character
- Followed by a dot
- At this point, it must not contain `css` or `html` at the end of the string
- Followed by 0 or more characters

This should in theory filter out all results that contain exactly `.css` or `.html` at the end.

Comment: Just to let you know. I answered another question regarding Regex with a Negative Lookahead and found the same issue. I spent some time and discovered the bug in DevTools and have submitted a fix, which I'm waiting on a review for. You can follow it here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=630852

Comment: Type resource-type:xhr in the filter for xhr.